# Pytorch - using pre-trained model, classifier training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'd like to use the pre-trained model and train the classifier part only, leaving the weights in the main part of the network unchanged.

I've imported the model, changed the output layer to match the number of classes I have in my data and instantiated the optimizer:

```
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.6.0', 'mobilenet_v2', pretrained=True, force_reload=True)

model.classifier[1] = nn.Linear(1280, 50, True)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(), lr=0.05)
```

Then in the training part I just do (as always):

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

In that manner, am I training only the classifier part of the network or it still somehow adjust the weights of the whole network and I'm missing something?

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-confirm-freezing-is-working/22648

Comment: thanks, it dispelled my doubts